# Atomic operation django

Tags: database, django, transactions, counter, atomic

I have updated to django 1.4 recently and have been working through a number of issues.

The most recent is atomic operations.

For some reason when a link is clicked the view is called twice. This has been verified by print statements on the development server.

As an example:

```
   def link_createNewNumber(self, request, obj=None):
      print "*** createNewNumber Called ***"
      number = numbers.objects.filter(id=obj)
      if len(number) == 1:
         print "Exists, just redirect to new page"
         # ResponseRedirect here...
      elif len(number) == 0:
         # Code to create new entry
         print "Saved new database entry"
         # ResponseRedirect here...
```

Now I stumbled across transactions, which seemed like what I needed. However, even after adding the transaction middleware to settings.py:

```
...
'django.middleware.transaction.TransactionMiddleware',
...
```

and @transaction.commit_on_success to the start of the function:

```
@transaction.commit_on_success
def link_createNewNumber(self, request, obj=None):
...
```

I often get the following output (simplified):

```
*** createNewNumber Called ***

*** createNewNumber Called ***

Saved new database entry

Saved new database entry
```

I am stumped, as this all used to work fine with 1.2.3. the core of the problem seems to be the double execution when the link is selected.

Comment: As an interesting side note, entering the URL manually in the address bar does NOT cause the view function to be called twice... The URL in the web page is: <a href="./link_createNewNumber/"><button>Create New Number</button></a>

Comment: Having noticed the above behavior about entering the URL directly allowed me to track down the issue of the double call. It was an issue with the trailing slash causing a redirect to the same url without it causing the code to execute twice. However while this addresses my issue, I beleive the question on transactions is still valid.